# Ionic 2 : Object 'Date' doesn't work on Ios

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, typescript, ionic2

I have an Ionic 2 app and I try to compare 2 date. 
To start, I have a date in a string format, like this : '2017-03-29 09:13:00'

I transform it to a date Object like this :

```
let myDate = new Date('2017-03-29 09:13:00');
```

And I try to compare my date, to the current day date

```
let today: Date = new Date();
let myDate = new Date('2017-03-29 09:13:00');
if(today == myDate) {
  return something...
}
```

This type of code **works good with ionic serve and ionic run android** (on a android device). The date format is : "*Wed Mar 29 2017 09:13:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)*"

But I have some problem with IOS device.

`let myDate = new Date('2017-03-29 09:13:00');` return me 'null'

and

`let today: Date = new Date();` return me this date format : "*2017-03-30T09:17:01.303Z*"

I don't understand why and what I have to do to have the "good" Date type on IOS devices.

Comment: let today: Date = new Date(); - is this just a typo in your question?

Comment: I'm assuming should be,     let today = Date();

Comment: I'm talking about how you are assigning to Date

Comment: For my own previous experiences in this specific cases, I would recommend you to always use **moment.js** to handle dates, regardless OS or whatever, just use moment.js. I had similar issues with some dates only, and using moment.js I solved them pretty easily: https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use moment.js like this: `moment('2017-03-29 09:13:00').toDate()`